# What to do after feature selection

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build a prediction model for anxiety, now I collected data from anxiety patients and non-anxiety ones, then after feature selection in R-programming, it gave me 13 important features, now what steps I have to follow and which algorithm's will be the best?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should go for Face Recognition using `python` this way you can identify the person's anxiety & based upon that data you can perform your code as well.

And I think `Local Binary Patterns Histograms` (LBPH) Face Recognizer is the best for your work as picture with low light doesn't effect the performance of algorithm & its an improvement of 2 well known Face Recognizer Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces.

It uses binary pattern like `11100011` to differentiate between people.

If you wish to read it further more about, please check this [link](https://github.com/informramiz/opencv-face-recognition-python)

I hope this solution might solve your problem : D

Comment: Happy to help you : D